# Button in a cell of easyiu-datgrid

Tags: datagrid, linkbutton, jquery-easyui

I have get a easyui-datagrid from a php file. I want insert a buttons on a colum, but I don´t know how to do it...
This is my code

```html
<table id="dg_lineas_albaran" class="easyui-datagrid"  style="width:700px;height:auto"
                data-options="
                    iconCls: 'icon-edit',
                    singleSelect: true,
                    toolbar: '#tb_lineas_albaran',
                    onClickRow: onClickRow
                ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th id="combo_productos" data-options="field:'cod_producto',width:60,
                    formatter:function(value,row){
                                return row.cod_producto;
                            },
                            editor:{
                                type:'combogrid',
                                options:{
                                    panelWidth: 500,
                                    idField: 'cod_producto',
                                    textField: 'cod_producto',
                                    mode: 'remote',
                                    url: 'get_productos_combo.php',
                                    columns: [[
                                        {field:'cod_producto',title:'Cod_producto',width:50,sortable:true},
                                        {field:'descripcion_producto',title:'Descripcion',width:150,sortable:true},
                                        
                                              ]],
                                    fitColumns: true,
                                    
                                }
                                
                            }
                            
                    ">CODIGO</th>
                   <th data-options="field:'descripcion_producto',width:250,editor:'text'">OBSERVACIONES</th>
                   <th data-options="field:'cantidad_producto',width:80,align:'right',editor:'numberbox'">Cantidad</th>
                   <th data-options="field:'precio_producto',width:80,align:'right',editor:{type:'numberbox',options:{precision:2}}">PRECIO</th>
                    <th data-options="field:'importe_producto',width:80,align:'right',editor:'numberbox'">IMPORTE</th>
                    <th data-options="field:'action',width:80,align:'right'"
                            
                    >NUM SERIE</th>
                    
                    <th data-options="field:'status',width:60,align:'center',editor:{type:'checkbox',options:{on:'P',off:''}}">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

I will like insert a button in the same colum than the combo and another one in the cell of NUM_SERIE to open a easyui-window.

Thank for all.

Comment: Why not use onClick or onDblClick to open the window instead of creating a button for it?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your javascript file inside `$(function(){ ... }`

```
$("#dg_lineas_albaran").datagrid({

    // Fires when data in datagrid is loaded successfully
    onLoadSuccess:function(){

        // Get this datagrid's panel object
        $(this).datagrid('getPanel')

            // for all easyui-linkbutton <a>'s make them a linkbutton
            .find('a.easyui-linkbutton').linkbutton();

    }

});
```

The problem is the data from the grid is loaded after the browser loads easyui. In order to get easyui to recognize the linkbuttons, you have to tell it to look for them after the data is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample add this to a data grid

```
<th field="PRO_RIF" align='right' width="50" formatter="acciones">Aciones</th>
```

a use this sample script

```
 <script>
function acciones(val,row){
        var url = 'print.php?id='+val;
        return '<a target="_blank" href="' + url + '"><button>Print</button></a>';
}
 </script>
```